# Highcharts Export to CSV No Data Grouping

Tags: highcharts, export-to-csv

https://github.com/highslide-software/export-csv

Using this plugin, is there any way to export the data from highcharts prior to it data grouping my data?

Data grouping or Data Approximation.

If I bring a lot of data back from the database, it is data grouping my dates so that there is a datapoint every couple hours, however when I download the data, i want it to download all of the data.

Is this possible?

Thank you!

Comment: When you take a look into to source code at line [#38](https://github.com/highslide-software/export-csv/blob/master/export-csv.js#L38) you will see `each()` for `series.points` which are actually rendered points. Try to use `series.options.data` to export all points from series.

Comment: I would like to mark your answer as an answer. This worked great. I did however have to format the date which is okay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you take a look into to source code at line [#38](https://github.com/highslide-software/export-csv/blob/master/export-csv.js#L38) you will see `each()` for `series.points` which are actually rendered points. Try to use `series.options.data` to export all points from series.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Loop the series and index values
    i = 0;
    each(this.series, function (series) {
        if (series.options.includeInCSVExport !== false) {
            names.push(series.name);


            each(series.options.data, function (point) {   //each(series.points, function (point) {
                if (!rows[point[0]]) {
                    rows[point[0]] = [];
                }
                rows[point[0]].x = point[0];

                rows[point[0]][i] = point[1];
            });
            i += 1;
        }
    })
```

This is what I changed that loop to, based on Pawels Answer.